# Angular - Accessing child components services

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

In an Angular app I have a situation where a component A holds an unspecified number of children of component type B (via *ngFor). I would like for component A to
push and receive data to and from the B components via a service b which each component B has its own instance of. Also the type-B components should be able to be introduced deeper in the component hierarchy (not a direct child) without introducing an output chain all the way down.

What would be the preferred way for A to gain access to the type-B components services?

An example would be: Some user gives input to one of the type-B components and this should update its index in the *ngFor in the A component.

I can think of accessing the services via viewChildren in the simple case, but are there a more general mechanism within the Angular dependency injection system that can be used?

Comment: I would rather rephrase the question, and ask how can I share a service between the parent component and the child components? That's an easier question to answer. You should also include details about what kind of data do you want to collect from the child components.

Comment: I know how to share one service between parent and children, but that is not the issue. An example would be: Some user input into one of the children should update its index in the *ngFor in the parent.

Comment: Exactly. You can achieve this by sharing the same instance of a service between your parent component and your child components. Add a BehaviorSubject to hold the data about how the children are displayed and update the index of a child item whenever you need. Listen for these changes in the parent component and trigger re-rendering.

Comment: @JacobNicolaisen do you have formControl in children BComponent and you want to share user input from those children with parent component?

Comment: @Octavian this is an ok solution and how I have allready done it, but I would like to know if how what I specifically ask for can be achieved. I can think of accessing the services via viewChildren but are there a more general mechanism within the Angular dependency injection system that can be used?

Comment: @navnath Yes it could be a formControl in children B-type Components and I want to share user input from those children with parent component and also sharing from parent to specific children. Specifically I want it done via individual services instantiated in the B-type components.

Comment: If you just want to share data related to `formControl` then you don't need service for that. I have a solution if  your req. is ..You want to set form control value of childern components from parent and change in formControl in children need to change value in parent for particular child..

Comment: I don't think you can have individual services on child level that are still a singleton for the parent, that is an upside down hierarchical tree. Why not simply use Input/Output for that where every child 'registers' itself with the parent?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.